# Dialog not scrollable when fill the screen

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm working on an android app. In one of the activities, I have a list of services and I want the user to rate each service. The services are in a `TableLayout` (each service in its own row). At the end of the row, I have a Rate `button`. When the user click on it, a `Dialog` pops up with `ratingBar`, `EditView` and two buttons at the bottom. My problem is that when the keyboard pops up on the button, and the user writes few lines in the `EditText` box, the keyword hides the buttons. Therefore, the user can't press the buttons, the user needs to minimize the keyboard in order to see the buttons.

**Now**, I saw few questions about the topic, but all of them had `xml` solutions. In my case, the dialog is all code, I don't use xml layout at this case. (I'm not sure it's the right way, but it works for my needs)

**Here is a picture**
[image: Here is the example of what happens]

**This is the code of the dialog**. This is what happen when clicking on the rate button.
Any ideas?

```
        e.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View v) {
                 boolean same = false;
                 TableRow row = new TableRow(QAListActivity.this); 
                 RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(QAListActivity.this);;
                 Dialog rankDialog = new Dialog(QAListActivity.this);

                 rankDialog.setContentView(R.layout.qa_rate);
                 rankDialog.setCancelable(true);
                 rankDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);


                 TableLayout table1 = new TableLayout(QAListActivity.this);
                 ArrayList<RatingBar> ratingBars = new ArrayList<RatingBar>();
                 EditText comment = new EditText(QAListActivity.this);

                 for(int z = 0; z < tour.QAList.size(); z++){
                     if(tour.QAList.get(z).getServiceType().equalsIgnoreCase(tour.voucherList.get(position).getServiceType())){
                         rankDialog.setTitle("Rate " + tour.voucherList.get(position).getDescription());
                         same = true;
                         row = new TableRow(QAListActivity.this); 
                         TextView text = new TextView(QAListActivity.this);
                         ratingBar = new RatingBar(QAListActivity.this);
                         ratingBars.add(ratingBar);
                         text.setText(tour.QAList.get(z).getQualityDesc());
                         text.setTextSize(20);
                         text.setHeight(40);
                         text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

                         row.addView(text);
                         row.addView(ratingBar);
                         row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                         table1.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                         tour.voucherList.get(position).voucher_rating.add(tour.QAList.get(z));
                     }
                 }

                 if(same){

                     String type = tour.voucherList.get(position).getServiceType();

                     if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("CNV")){

                         String[] qa_bus = {"Bus Make","Bus Year","Number of Seats","Bus Company","Bathroom on Bus?","Driver's Name",
                                 "Driver speaks English","Helpfulness of driver (on/off bus)","Were there Gate1 signs on the bus?"};
                         TableLayout table_bus = new TableLayout(QAListActivity.this);

                         for(int count = 0; count < qa_bus.length; count++){
                             TableRow row_make = new TableRow(QAListActivity.this);
                             EditText make = new EditText(QAListActivity.this);
                             make.setHint(qa_bus[count]);
                             make.setWidth(table.getWidth()/2+50);
                             row_make.addView(make);
                             row_make.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                             table_bus.addView(row_make, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                         }
                         table1.addView(table_bus);     
                     }
                     else{
                         TableLayout table_comment = new TableLayout(QAListActivity.this);
                         TableRow row_comment = new TableRow(QAListActivity.this);
                         comment = new EditText(QAListActivity.this);

                         comment.setHint("Remarks");
                         comment.setWidth(table.getWidth()/2+50);

                         row_comment.addView(comment);
                         row_comment.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                         table_comment.addView(row_comment, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                         table1.addView(table_comment);     
                     }

                     TableLayout table_buttons = new TableLayout(QAListActivity.this);
                     TableRow save_row = new TableRow(QAListActivity.this); 
                     Button save = new Button(QAListActivity.this);
                     save.setText("Save");
                     save_row.addView(save);    
                     save_row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                     final Dialog rankDialogTemp = rankDialog;
                     final ArrayList<RatingBar> ratingBarsTemp = ratingBars;
                     final EditText remarksTemp = comment;
                     save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                         public void onClick(View v) {
                             for(int xx = 0; xx < ratingBarsTemp.size(); xx++){
                                 Log.d("ratingBar", "" + ratingBarsTemp.get(xx).getRating());
                                 tour.voucherList.get(position).voucher_rating.get(xx).setRating(ratingBarsTemp.get(xx).getRating());
                             }
                             tour.voucherList.get(position).setQAcompleted(true);
                             tour.voucherList.get(position).setRemarks(remarksTemp.getText().toString());
                             rowTemp.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                             getInfo.saveOfflineData(QAListActivity.this, new Gson().toJson(TourListActivity.TourList), DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
                             rankDialogTemp.dismiss();   
                         }
                     });

                     Button back = new Button(QAListActivity.this);
                     back.setText("Back");
                     save_row.addView(back);    
                     back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                             rankDialogTemp.dismiss();   
                         }
                     });                             
                     table_buttons.addView(save_row);
                     table1.addView(table_buttons); 

                 }
                 rankDialog.addContentView(table1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

                 //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
                 rankDialog.show();                
             }
         });
```

My `qa_rate.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/qa_rate"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TableLayout  
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    </TableLayout >
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: You should define a layout, put all things into a [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). Then inflate the layout to the dialog in runtime.

Comment: Can you add your xml layout

Comment: anyone? the dialog is in scrollview already

Answer (score 0):

Maybe play with the windowSoftInputMode

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Or maybe put your buttons in a scroll view so the user can scroll down to it.

Comment: But the buttons are part of the table in the dialog box. The buttons are in the last row of the table.

Comment: Put the whole table in a scroll view. You can Dynamically do this if you don't want to define a xml Layout. Although I highly recommend you do switch to xml layouts they are much easier to use. Can you show me your code? Where do you add the table to the view?

Comment: Did you see the code? anyone? the dialog is in scrollview already